How to do Bayesian MCMC with Compositional Parameter Constraints
So I know that if you have parameter constraints and you were to do a random walk MH without them, you can use a truncated normal distribution as your proposal instead (and of course, this would be reflected in the Hasting ratio as symmetry is lost). But what if were are doing this for say, a 3-component Gaussian Mixture Model? What is the best way to constrain the first two proportion parameters to sum less than or equal to one? Of course, the third proportion parameter isn't a parameter to be solved, since it is a function of the first two. Thanks in advance!

This model is easy to code in Stan, if you're willing to do that

Thanks! I have no constraints on the program I use. How does it work?

I think it's conventional to sample mixing proportions from a Dirichlet distribution; that guarantees that they add up to 1, iirc. By the way, are you sure you need to do sampling (as opposed to a deterministic computation)? For conventional assumptions about the distributions of the mixing parameters and per-bump distributions, I seem to recall there is a neat posterior; I forget what it might be. You would only need to carry out sampling if you are bending some of the conventional assumptions. Sampling is so tremendously inefficient that I would only resort to that if it's really necessary.

PS. While it's an interesting question, it's off topic here; try stats.stackexchange.com for followups.

Thank you so much. I think I will post there for follow-ups, but I think sampling from Dirichlet for proportions is a good place to start.

Yep- for what I'm doing, I "must" sample :(

Google stan gaussian mixture
